# HTML arrange forms

Tags: html, forms, input

I have multiple tables on one HTML page. There is one input field and a submit button that are in placed in different tables.
Inbetween them, there are other forms used as simple links that should look like ordinary buttons.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="/link1"><input type="submit" value="Link" /></form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="I_need_that_to_be_sent"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="/link2"><input type="submit" value="Link2" /></form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What could be a good solution to get the input field submitted when the submit button is pressed and the links stay formatted as buttons?
I do not want to use JavaScript.
The following construction for the links to avoid the forms in between did not work:

```
<a href="link1"><button>Link</button></a>
```

Firefox did submit the form instead of calling the link.
Thank you

Comment: You can not nest forms into each other. If you want a link to _look_ like a button, then format it with CSS accordingly instead of producing invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks but that's the reason I ask.
Links that are formatted via css do usually not look like real buttons and thats what I try to do.

Comment: Well if it is that important that they look exactly like input buttons, then ditch the nested forms and use input elements of `type=button` only – and give them an onclick handler via JavaScript, that redirects to the desired target address (that you can specify on the element itself f.e. via a _custom data attribute_).